# Extjs Tab Panel with CodeMirror

Tags: extjs, tabs, codemirror

I try to use [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) in a TabPanel.

http://jsfiddle.net/2dv2z/6/

I have 2 problems which block me:

- It's not possible to change the tab
- The CodeMirror Element does not really fit his container...

Has anyone some ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

I have developed an extjs component for codemirror. Have a look here http://www.mzsolutions.eu/extjs/#!/api/Ext.ux.form.field.CodeMirror

Cheers

Comment: I will take a look of it for resizing. I finally succeed, here is for Extjs 4.07: http://jsfiddle.net/mp35b/ and for Extjs 4.1: http://jsfiddle.net/cKv6b/ I just have some troubles with 4.1, here are more explanations: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196833-Code-Mirror-in-a-TabPanel&p=785563&viewfull=1#post785563